# Oracle: VarChar(hh24:mm:ss) - timestamp, how to?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I'm used to SQL Server and datediff, time data types.  Pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.

Column 1: Timestamp
Column 2: Varchar(200) in the form HH24:MM:SS

Trying to do:

```
SELECT Varchar(200) - Timestamp AS Difference
FROM table
```

Can't figure out the right way to do this, queries are getting ridiculously complicated.

Comment: I don't understand, you subtract a timestamp from an interval. That doesn't make sense. What should be the result, a timestamp or an interval? Or should the interval information represent another timestamp. Please clarify.

Comment: I didn't design the database, this is what I'm left with.  I have a timestamp that an event occurred at and a varchar storing an associated time.  I'm trying to get the difference between the two times.

Comment: But what should be the outcome? For instance `'12:34:56' - TIMESTAMP'2015-12-04 12:34:56` - what result do you expect?

Comment: I expect the time in the Timestamp to be a lesser value than the time in the VarChar, I'm trying to capture the average duration between the two.

Comment: So, do you expect that `varchar(200)` to represent a timestamp on the same day as the `timestamp` column but at a different time?  And then you can subtract the two timestamps and end up with an interval?

Comment: Exactly correct sir.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible oracle select statement to solve your problem.

A simple explanation of the code:
select to_date(char) - to_date(to_char(date)) as difference from table;
you need to convert the varchar(200) to date and convert the timestamp to the same date format in varchar then finally convert the timestamp varchar into date format.

That should work.

```
select to_date('17:15:30', 'HH24:MI:SS')- to_date(to_char(systimestamp, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24:MI:SS') as difference from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are few date/timestamp/interval manipulation examples, hope this helps:

```
SELECT
    TO_DSINTERVAL('0 ' || timeinstring) - NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'SSSSS'), 'SECOND') RESULT_AS_INTERVAL,
    TRUNC(timestamp) + (TO_DSINTERVAL('0 ' || timeinstring) - NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'SSSSS'), 'SECOND')) RESULT_AS_DATE,
    TO_CHAR(DATE'1-1-1' + (TO_DSINTERVAL('0 ' || timeinstring) - NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'SSSSS'), 'SECOND')), 'HH24:MI:SS') RESULT_AS_TIMESTRING
    FROM
        (SELECT TIMESTAMP'2015-12-04 12:34:56' timestamp, '23:34:45' timeInString  FROM DUAL) sample_data;

RESULT_AS_INTERVAL                 RESULT_AS_DATE      RESULT_AS_TIMESTRING
---------------------------------- ------------------- --------------------
+000000000 10:59:49.000000000      04.12.2015 10:59:49 10:59:49
```